# does "land on something" means agree on something?

Tags: meaning

in a movie, two actors had this conversation :

player A: Oh you bought a chair!

player B: Uh, no actually , I borrowed it like we talked about (explanation: he took the chair from his office)

Player A : I thought we decided that it is like stealing

Player B :  **is that what we landed on that?**

what does last sentence mean?

Comment: The whole dialogue is not excellent English. Like you, I'd interpret "landed" in this example as "agreed upon," but it's not a usage that is common among people with whom I typically converse: it sounds sub-literate to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes.

I imagine that the actual text is

> Is that **where** we landed on that?

The interpretation is that in the course of the discussion there were several possible outcomes and they finally arrived at an agreement that it was stealing.

This is not a common idiom.  It's easily understood but I'm not sure of its origins and I have never said it.  Was this an old movie?  Perhaps it's a usage that has fallen out of favor.

Comment: thank you for answer! yes I was watching Arrested development that it was made in 2000. so it is old somehow.

Comment: Haha, not so old.  It could just be a phrase no one has used around me so it feels unfamiliar.